# Do we need to install JDK to run WebDriver's TestNG tests through command line?

Tags: selenium, command-line, selenium-webdriver, testng, ui-automation

I am new to Selenium/WebDriver and created a project which I can execute through Eclipse IDE successfully. Now, I plan to run the test through command prompt by creating the proper TestNG1.xml and making sure the testng-6.8.5.jar is correctly pointed in PATH. I even tried giving full path of the testng-6.8.5.jar. Unfortunately I keep getting the error,
*Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG*

I don't have JDK installed (and I don't want to install) so wondering if JDK is mandatory to run TestNG tests from Command line? From above error it looks like it's not even trying to access the TestNG1.xml I have.

I plan to distribute these tests as group of files to my fellow Business Analyst who only have JRE installed on their machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having JRE is enough to run the TestNG tests, or no need to install JDK to run the TestNG tests through command line

the issue was with the testng-6.8.5.jar library as selenium-server-standalone-2.32.0.jar was allowing me to run the project with no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need JDK installed where you are going to run your Test [Here is some documentation of TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do you know if there is a workaround? Something like specify a jar file in Classpath. What is this testng-jdk15.jar for?

Comment: Hi, testng-jdk.jar contains the classes for example "org.testng.TestNG.class" which is the main entry point for running tests in the TestNG framework.

look here you can see what it does contain http://testng.org/javadoc/

Comment: Just want to update you that installing JDK didn't solve the error. So, most likely I need to figure out the missing step I am performing to get that main class not found error.